How to replace double quotes within a string (only in the middle)
I asked this question to chatGpt, he gave me this regex and example:
let str = '"This is a "test" string with "quotes" in the middle."';
let result = str.replace(/(?<=^|[^"])(")(?=\S.*")/g, 'replacement');
console.log(result);

But I still get the first double quotes in the begining of the string replaced
//replacementThis is a replacementtest" string with replacementquotes" in the middle."

I need only the doubles quotes in the middle to be replaced, not in the beginning or the end.

Just assert that before the quote we're not at the start of the string, and that after the quote we're not at the end of it:


let str = '"This is a "test" string with "quotes" in the middle."';
let result = str.replace(/(?!^)"(?!$)/g, '#');
console.log(result);





But I still get the first double quotes in the begining of the string
replaced

That is because your pattern starts with an alternation (?<=^|[^"])  asserting either the start of the string or a character other than " directly to the left (where the negated charcter class [^"] could also match a newline)
If you want to use positive lookaround assertions, you can assert that there should be a character to the left and to the right, where the dot can also match a space:
(?<=.)"(?=.)

See a regex demo


let str = '"This is a "test" string with "quotes" in the middle."';
let result = str.replace(/(?<=.)"(?=.)/g, '[replacement]');
console.log(result);



If there should be a non whitespace character other than " to the left and to the right:
(?<=[^\s"][^"\n]*)"(?=[^"\n]*[^\s"])

See a regex demo.
